# Understanding Javascript Streams, basic example question

Tags: javascript, browser

#### Context

In my current understanding, the `ReadableStream` constructor allows you to chop big pieces of data into smaller pieces (chunks) that you can then read.

In the case of `fetch` you already get the ReadableStream ready to consume, i.e the data is already in chunks, and can be found at the response's `body`. But we may also want to produce a stream (for others to consume.)

A use case of this would any very large file uploaded by the user, that has to be processed by pieces.

---

So the doubt is what is the difference between `start` running sync or async code, as I show below.

Basic syntax and example (uses `var` to easy copy/paste in the console):

```js
var u8View = new Uint8Array(30); //typed array with 30 zeros.

var stream = new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    // to an approx. this will create an "array of chunks" from u8View that a user can access later
    controller.enqueue(u8View)
    controller.close()
  }
})

stream.getReader().read().then(d => console.log(d))


var stream1 = new ReadableStream({
  start(controller) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      controller.enqueue(u8View)
      controller.close()
    }, 1000)
  }
})

stream1.getReader().read().then(d => console.log(d))
```

You will notice that the code basically does the same.

I believe this is because `read` only passes the value once it is fulfilled (resolved or rejected). [I take this from a comment in the MDN's example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader#examples).

- Is this correct?
- Why does it seem weird to me, is this just a common/expected behaviour?
- So as long as you make sure to `enqueue` something, it doesn't really matter how you handle the code (even if looping through the chunks)?

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, the `read` function resolved with special object which contain chunk's value and `done` flag which indicate last chunk. So if you want to consume a whole stream, you should handle `done` flag properly.

```
var reader = stream.getReader();
reader.read().then(function processChunk({done, value}) {
   console.log('chunk value:', value);
   if (done) {
     console.log('stream closed!');
     return;
   }
   // otherwise continue process chunks
   reader.read().then(processChunk);
});
```

In your example for the reader consumer, only **one difference** between `stream` and `stream1`. For `stream1` reader will receive the first chunk on **1 second later** than reader of `stream`